# How to use Wikipedia API to expand entities?

Tags: entity, wikipedia-api, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

I'm working on my thesis and I encountered a problem i don't know hot to approach properly.

I'm clustering tweets and given the few information they carry, I want to expand the entities I find in the text by accesing Wikipedia and taking the information about these into account.

My problem comes when I start looking at Wikipedia [API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki). It has so many properties and so many configuration possibles that I don't know how to extract relevant information from the articles that I can use to relate entities between one another.

I didn't just have a look and said uff too difficult and came here to ask. I tried things and at least I know that the things I should ask the API about are ***props*** and not ***lists*** or ***meta*** infromation.

I tried for example *prop=linkshere* as Action for a query about Pau Gasol and according to the Documentation: *Find all pages that link to the given pages* but I get [image: Information retrieved by Wikipedia API that relates Pau Gasol with Kareem Abdul-Jabar] and when I go to Kareem Abdul-Jabar page(same pageid) neither I don't find any reference to Pau nor I don't find any to Kareem from Pau's

What is the best query to expand an entity in wikipedia?

Comment: Did you take *redirects* into account? Also, *what* do you want to expand them to?

Comment: Also, **hitting the Wikipedia API for every tweet will not scale**. Use an approach that does *not* rely on public APIs.

Comment: I'm opened to use any part of the API so redirects can also be considered. I was thinking about something that if for example, I find Pau Gasol in a tweet and Rudy Gay in another, by accesing Wikipedia I find that they are related by NBA, should I consider DBPedia instead?

Comment: Also, Kareem Abdul-Jabar *does* link to Pau Gasol. Hidden deep in the navigation templates... its there, but it is an entirely meaningless link. So first **figure out *what* you want to do**. We can't help you otherwise.

Comment: I'll find out exactly what I want and come back here, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

It comes from navboxes like [`Template:Los Angeles Lakers 2009–10 NBA champions`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Los_Angeles_Lakers_2009%E2%80%9310_NBA_champions) that are [transcluded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Transclusion) at the bottom of the page and collapsed by default in the "Links to related articles" box.